# Select latest updated file from directory and send it via email

Tags: shell, scripting, email, mutt

I want to select latest error(timestamp).log file from some directory and send it via email as attachment. What I am trying is:

Filename: abc.sh

```
echo 'An error occured' | mutt -s "Logs" -a '/xx/xx/logs/xx/*.log(.om[1])' -e 'my_hdr From:xx@xx.com' -- xx@xx.com
```

Comment: What does `(.om[1])` signify?  Is this part of the file name?

Comment: I found that here and was trying to use that in my code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015678/linux-most-recent-file-in-a-directory

Comment: Is there any other way to attach latest logs in email?

Comment: @John1024 - that's a `zsh` _glob qualifier_. It sorts (`o`) plain files (`.`) by the time of the last modification (`m`) and selects only the first (`[1]`) one.

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks.  `zsh` has some nice features.

Comment: Yes I agree zsh has some really nice features. Wish it worked for me but unfortunately I cannot used zsh for my code.

Answer (score 3):

#### Naive Solution

I will assume that your logs have file names which match the glob `/xx/xx/logs/xx/*.log` and that you want to send mail to `somebody@host.com`

```
newest=$(ls -rt /xx/xx/logs/xx/*.log | tail -n 1)
echo 'An error occured' | mutt somebody@host.com -s "Logs" -a "$newest"
```

This approach works if the files have well-behaved names.  In general, though, parsing the output of `ls` is unreliable.

#### More Reliable Solution

This avoids using `ls` and will be safe for any and all file names:

```
inode=$(find /xx/xx/logs/xx/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.log' -printf '%T@ %i\n' | sort -rn | awk '{print $2;exit;}')
newest=$(find /xx/xx/logs/xx/ -maxdepth 1 -inum "$inode")
echo 'An error occured' | mutt somebody@host.com -s "Logs" -a "$newest"
```

#### Testing to see which file is selected

To see which file is the newest, without emailing it, run:

```
inode=$(find /xx/xx/logs/xx/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.log' -printf '%T@ %i\n' | sort -rn | awk '{print $2;exit;}')
newest=$(find /xx/xx/logs/xx/ -maxdepth 1 -inum "$inode")
echo "newest file is $newest"
```

Comment: the log file name changes and every time timestamp is added to the log file.

Comment: _"the log file name changes"_  OK.  This solution finds the most recent file in the `xx/xx/logs/xx/` directory that has a name ending in `.log`.  Do you need something else?  _"every time timestamp is added to the log file"_  The contents of the log file will all be sent in the email.

Comment: When I tried using this code I got this error:


find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-iname `/xx/xx/logs/xx/*.log'' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ `/xx/xx/logs/xx/*.log''.
find: missing argument to `-inum'
Can't stat (null): Bad address
(null): unable to attach file.

Comment: Oops, sorry!  Answer corrected.

Comment: Hi,
But it still gives me this error:

Can't stat (null): Bad address
(null): unable to attach file.

Comment: Hey thanks, it did work after the last correction. I really really appreciate your help.
THANKS A TON!!!

Comment: This code is not sending the newest file created. HELP!!!

Comment: @Brinda I added a section above showing how to just print out the name of the most recent log file so that you can verify that it is the most recent.  If it isn't, then I need to know more, such as what was the name of the file selected and the name of the most recent file.

Comment: I have a job which will run every minute and create an error log if the job fails. The error log will be created according to timestamp that is errorLog070820151018.log errorLog070820151020.log Now I have to find the latest log from the folder and send it via email. In this case the latest log will be errorLog070820151020.log so this log should be selected and send via email.

Comment: @Brinda Excellent!